# Getting values from options page to css

Tags: css, pages, options, variables

i got an options page that needs to affects a certain (for now) css value..

i have about using php variables in css and creating custom global variables in wordpress but havent something easy enough to understand so i have done this and places it in my header file

`<style type="text/css">
.current-menu-item {
    background: <?php echo get_option('sg_currentbuttoncolor'); ?> !important;
}
</style>`

does that look like a good solution to you?
what is the preffered way of creating changes in my css using values from my options page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it correctly. I would suggest two enhancements:

1. Do not put this code directly in header.php. Create a custom function to print the css and hook this into the wp_head action.
2. Always sanitize/escape input before you print it to the screen. Look into ctype_xdigit() for creating a custom function to sanitize you color value.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more appropriate to hook this into `wp_print_styles`?

Comment: Maybe ... but then you need to check if you're in the admin which is unnecessary IMHO. I like to follow the rule "Hook in as late as possible, but no later". wp_head fits the bill rather well and it *should* only fire in the front-end.